# How to show first commit for subversion sub folder / project by 'svn log'?

Tags: svn, version-control

I have a project which has long history. I want to show the first commit on svn for svn subfolder / subproject.

If I try `svn log -r 1` it shows the following error:

> `svn: E195012: Unable to find repository location for 'URL' in revision 1`

How do I do this?

Answer (score -2):

You can show the first commit using the following command.:

```
svn log -r 1:HEAD --limit 1
```

Answer (score -2):

1. First commit in SVN-repo (with unmodified history) **always** have revision number 1
2. According to `svn help log`, you can always see only part of history, using `-r` option

Thus, following pp. 1-2 you have to use

```
svn log -r 1 <URL-or-PATH>
```

Comment: Does not work `svn log -r 1` shows `svn: E195012: Unable to find repository location for 'URL' in revision 1`